# Trying to update a node value of XML and it's throwing an exception

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nodes

I'm trying to update a node value from a XML file but when I'm trying to do this action is throwing an exception "Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This is what I have:

```
public void UpdateXMLValues(List<string> values)
{
    XmlNode node;
    xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(XMLInterfaces);
    node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("Servers/MYSERVER");
    XMLValues = new List<string>(values);
    node.Attributes["Host"].Value = XMLValues[0];
    xmldoc.Save(XMLInterfaces);
}
```

and this is my XML information:

```
<Servers>
  <MYSERVER>
    <Host>0.0.0.0</Host>
    <Port>23</Port>
    <User>TestingUser</User>
    <Password>/NNfWRStbZsUyc88S5tjhA==</Password>
  </MYSERVER>
</Servers>
```

When I press F11 in the line node.Attributes["Host"].values = XMLValues[0]; I'm getting the error

any idea?

Comment: Looks like your xml is not valid, <MYSERVER> needs either a closing tag </MYSERVER> or it needs to be self-closing <MYSERVER/>

Comment: Sorry! It has the close label, just I didn't add here in my example...

Comment: Can you update your question with the proper xml? Where does the closing tag sit?

Answer (score 2):

`Host` is not an *attribute* of the `MYSERVER` element. It's an *element* inside it.

You can access it like so:

```
var hostNode = node["Host"];
hostNode.Value = XMLValues[0];
```

For reference, if it was an attribute, your XML would look like this:

```
<MYSERVER host="some_host">
</MYSERVER>
```

Comment: If is not an attribute, then how could i update that value?

Comment: I've updated the question to include how to update the value.

Comment: I'm getting this using this solution:

    var hostNode = node["Host"];
    hostNode.Value = XMLValues[0];

Comment: @JavierSalas Errr - do you have an error or something? I'm not really sure what you're saying.